# Show both relative and absolute difference in Plotly Indicator python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to use plotly.graph_objs.Indicator for showing output.

```
go.Indicator(mode = "number+delta", value = 200,
             number = {'font': {'size': 30}},
             title = {'text': 'HEAD', 'font':{'size':20, 'color':'green'}},
             domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
             delta = {'reference':300, 'relative':False})
```

Here if I pass relative=True, relative difference will be shown for eg. 30%.

If I pass relative=False, absolute difference will be shown for eg. -20

Is there any way to get both the absolute & relative difference.

Comment: Do you want the delta symbol to show for both absolute and relative difference? Or would you be fine with the relative difference being an annotation next to the absolute difference?

Comment: Hi @DerekO, Ideal case would be having an option to choose whether all three appear or some. But for now if we have any hack for showing only relative and absolute difference without symbol, even that would work, as symbol can be notified by red/green color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the relative and absolute changes are calculated internally by the go.Indicator method (meaning that you can't customize the text to be displayed next to the delta symbol), and that you have to choose between relative or absolute change to be displayed.

The simplest solution would be to add a text annotation. However, standalone text isn't a graph_object, but is rendered over the figure. This means the text can overlap other graph objects in the figure.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta", 
    value = 200,
    number = {'font': {'size': 30}},
    title = {'text': 'HEAD', 'font':{'size':20, 'color':'green'}},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    delta = {'reference':300, 'relative':False})
)

fig.add_annotation(x=0.5, y=0.4, text="-30%", font=dict(color="red"), showarrow=False)

fig.show()
```

The figure looks okay with a fairly large browser window:

[image]

But when you resize the browser window, the text annotation can overlap the go.Indicator object which is ugly:

[image]

A better but hacky solution is to add three different go.Indicator objects as traces: the first two go.Indicator objects will display relative and absolute changes but we will set the font color of the numbers to be the background color so they aren't visible. Then the third go.Indicator object adds the number `200` and the title `HEAD` without showing the delta. The last thing is to set the domain of each of these go.Indicator objects accordingly so that they don't overlap as you resize your browser window.

You can adjust the domain of each of these traces to get you closer to the result you're looking for.

```
fig = go.Figure()

# the first two traces are just the delta with the value set to the background color
fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta", 
    value = 200,
    number = {'font': {'size': 30, 'color':'rgb(255,255,255,0)'}},
    domain = {'x': [0, 0.8], 'y': [0, 0.8]},
    delta = {'reference':300, 'relative':False})
)

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta", 
    value = 200,
    number = {'font': {'size': 30, 'color':'rgb(255,255,255,0)'}},
    domain = {'x': [0.2, 1], 'y': [0, 0.8]},
    delta = {'reference':300, 'relative':True})
)

## this adds the title and value
fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number", 
    value = 200,
    number = {'font': {'size': 30}},
    title = {'text': 'HEAD', 'font':{'size':20, 'color':'green'}},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]})
)

fig.show()
```

This is what the figure looks like with a large browser window:

[image]

When you resize the browser window, the go.Indicator traces remain distinct:

[image]

Comment: I really love your hack. Meanwhile if dash developers could work this side, it will be add more power to Indicator object.